# Generate a set of all possible records in TLA+

Tags: tla+

Suppose

```
keyset == {"k1", "k2"}
valueset == {"v1", "v2"}
```

I want to generate a set of all 4 possible record

```
{
  [k1 |-> v1, k2 |-> v1],
  [k1 |-> v1, k2 |-> v2],
  [k1 |-> v2, k2 |-> v1],
  [k1 |-> v2, k2 |-> v2]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function set:

```
AllKVs == [keyset -> valueset]
```